# How to "select" TextNode? (TipTap/Prosemirror APIs)

Tags: javascript, dom, tiptap, prose-mirror

**This question is only related to TipTap/Prosemirror and it's APIs.**

Hey!

I have a TextNode (pic attached), which I extracted from the editor. And also I have a mark applied to this TextNode. And I want to unset this specific mark from the TextNode that I have.

Main point here is that I need to unset a mark without manual selection from the user.

I've tried a lot to create prosemirror Selection on fly and then toggle mark, but to instantiate Selection you need to provide positions, and I don't have them. And also I cannot find a way to get them somehow.

Also it's not really clear for me why TextNode is not selectable? I mean it's property https://tiptap.dev/api/schema#selectable.
Because of that I wasn't able to create NodeSelection via [https://prosemirror.net/docs/ref/#state.NodeSelection^create](https://prosemirror.net/docs/ref/#state.NodeSelection%5Ecreate).
Probably there are some options to make it selectable?

Finally I even tried to just create WEB API Selection from Ranges - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection, but seems like it's not possible, seems like tiptap or prosemirror preventing me to do that.

I'm one step away from just rough update directly in the JSON of my editor's content, because I can't find other options to make it correctly through APIs.

Probably you can suggest something?

Thanks in advance!

[image: TextNode]

Answer (score 0):

its a bit late, but you dont add / remove marks on a node directly.. you should do this on a transaction or a command.

example transaction:

```
tr.addMark(
  pos,
  pos + node.nodeSize,
  schema.marks.myMark.create(myAttribiutes)
);
```

example command:

```
editor.commands.setMark('myMark', myAttributes);
```

or

```
chain().setMark('myMark', myAttributes).run();
```

Note: the tr objects seem to behave somehow inconsitent sometimes, but you should be able to use the tr from the commandProps.

in case you want to take the command approach and want to set the selection where you want to add the mark manually`setNodeSelection` or `setTextSelection` in the chain.

goof luck